# CodeIgniter 4 running on Wamp

Tags: codeigniter, wamp

I'am trying to install CodeIgniter 4.0.2. on Wamp 3.2.0 with PHP 7.3.12.

I've created a virtual host with the Wamp virtual host form (and \etc\hosts for Windows 10), which produces this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName www.ci4.dvp
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ci4/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/ci4/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

Note that I pointed to the "public/" directory like indicated in the CI4 documentation.

The error I have in browser (Chrome) is:

*Ce site est inaccessible.
Impossible de trouver l'adresse IP du serveur de ci4.dvp.
Essayez d'exécuter les diagnostics réseau de Windows.
DNS_PROBE_FINISHED_NXDOMAIN*

What's wrong?

It runs correctly with the spark server (at localhost:8080).

Comment: Can you also show your HOSTS file from `c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`

Comment: 127.0.0.1 www.ci4.dvp                ::1 www.ci4.dvp

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1 ci4.dvp` and `::1 ci4.dvp`

Comment: And maybe `ServerName ci4.dvp` also

Comment: With a `ServerAlias www.ci4.dvp`

Comment: it runs! Thanks you very much RiggsFolly! Have a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

Change your HOSTS file to

```
127.0.0.1 ci4.dvp 
::1 ci4.dvp
```

And the Vhost to

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName ci4.dvp
    ServerAlias www.ci4.dvp
    DocumentRoot "c:/wamp/www/ci4/public"
    <Directory  "c:/wamp/www/ci4/public/">
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
        AllowOverride All
        Require local
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```